# How i can fix error Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int

Tags: laravel

My page should display the sum from different tables. When i try make sum with code:

```
        $games = Game::where('winner_id', $user->id)->get();
        $games_low = GameLow::where('winner_id', $user->id)->get();
        $wins = $games + $games_low->count();
        $wins = $wins;
        $totalBank = $games->sum('price');
```

I received error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int`. How i can fix this problem?

Comment: What is `$gamesPlayed`?

Comment: this is displayed counts of game from database, i don't use `$winrate` and `$gamesPlayed` variables on blade, i edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue - Collection

Error caused using `+` to object (`$games`) and numbers (`$games_low->count()`).

```php
$games     = Game::where('winner_id', $user->id)->get(); // Collection
$games_low = GameLow::where('winner_id', $user->id)->get(); // Collection

$games_low->count() // int
```

## Solution

Use `count` for `Game` and `GameLow`

```php
$games     = Game::where('winner_id', $user->id)->count();
$games_low = GameLow::where('winner_id', $user->id)->count();
$wins      = $games + $games_low;

dd($wins);
```

---

#### Update

> how i can correctly display the sum of variables? before when I had one variable, I used `$totalBank = $games->sum('price');` how i need now display sum `$games` and `$games_low`, i don't know

```php
$games     = Game::where('winner_id', $user->id);
$games_low = GameLow::where('winner_id', $user->id);
$wins      = $games->count() + $games_low->count();
$totalBank = $games->sum('price');
```

Comment: yes, it works!! and last question: how i can correctly display the sum of variables? before when I had one variable, I used `$totalBank = $games->sum('price');` how i need now display sum `$games` and `$games_low`, i don't know

Comment: Check my answer :)